# AWS SNS Notification not received if i tested with ipa generated from any xcode 6 version, how to solve it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I had coded in ios to receive Notifications sent from "AWS SNS", notification is received if i connect the device directly to xcode and run, if i created ipa from xcode version less than 6 or ipa generation through iTunes then notification received perfectly. If i generate ipa from any xcode 6 version then notification is not received, how to fix this ? And i am using Development provisioning profile and development certificate with Push notification service enabled.

didFinishLaunchWithOptions code

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    [self showAlertIfNotificationReceives: userInfo];
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{
NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
// Register with AWS SNS
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error{
    NSLog(@"Failed to register with error : %@", error);
}

//Handle Notification if App is Open
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"SNS Notification userInfo: %@",userInfo);
}
```

I am receiving device token and registered with AWS SNS successfully, but i am not receiving a notification only with ipa of xcode 6 version. Advance thanks for any help.

Comment: r u tested in the APNS in background mode or foreground mode

Comment: Notification will be handled both in background and foreground mode and i  had tested, Working fine other than xcode 6 version ipa

Comment: then APNS is not the problem , show your **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** code for declared the **UIUserNotificationType**

Comment: I had shown didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code

Comment: sry bro , if we need to check the code , k have a nice day , I delete my answer

Comment: Thanks for help. Thanks a lot. If i get answer, i will get back to you

Comment: Bro, problem is "Invalid token receives from APNS while sending a notification(But app successfully registers with APNS and showing invalid token only while sending notification)

Comment: yesterday  I asked this question you are replied I used the valid token , now u telling invalid token, now its working or not bro

Comment: Thing is "Token generated by APNS and registered successfully with AWS SNS Server, only while sending notification it shows error log as invalid token". Not Working bro

Comment: r u tried in developer or distribution mode , if it is developer mode try another device

Comment: Thanks bro, finally problem was identified as in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode version 6.4 automatically takes "Distribution Certificate" to generate ipa even though "Development certificate and development provisioning profile were selected"(I don't know why)

Problem is : App registers in Production APNS because of xcode automatic selection of Distribution certificate for ipa generation and AWS SNS APNS Sandbox Server is a trying to send notification to Production APNS Server Device Token.

Finally, AWS SNS Production Application created to send notifications